# Numerous Instance Attributes Inherited from Multiple Classes

Tags: python

Say I have classes A, B, and C. Each of them has over 10 instance attributes. I am going to create class D that inherits classes A, B, and C. What is the best practice to organize the numerous instance attributes in class D? Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d,...):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        ...

class B:
    def __init__(self, e, f, g, h,...):
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
        self.g = g
        self.h = h
        ...

class C:
    def __init__(self, i, j, k, l,...):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.k = k
        self.l = l
        ...

class D(A, B, C):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, ..., z):
        A.__init__(self, a, b, c, d,...)
        B.__init__(self, e, f, g, h,...)
        C.__init__(self, i, j, k, l,...)
        self.z = z
```

Comment: Defining a class hierarchy like this in the first place is usually a bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by organize?  I see nothing wrong with the example you gave other than the huge complexity.

Comment: The classes' attributes should already be organised by function (I'm assuming that you're going for something like mixins/traits). If not, you might want to look into either a redesign or composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the list unpack operator is helpful here—

```
manyargs = [a, b, ...]

class D(A, B, C):
    def __init__(self, *manyargs):
        ...
```

Also, probably might be helpful to read about super()